# iOS 17 beta 3 keyboard covers textfield

Tags: ios, keyboard, beta

I just installed iOS 17 beta 3 and the keyboard covers the TextFiled (in swiftUI). The app works fine on the simulator and also fine under iOS 16.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s a bug. I can confirm. Also the TextEditor has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

new iOS beta has fixed this problem

Comment: I'm on the latest beta and still seeing the issue btw. 11 Pro Max